# $\mathsf{DSPACE}(n) \subsetneq \mathbb{E}$: there is a decidable language no LBA can handle..

Tags: decidability

Use the following lemma and diagonalisation:

Lemma: Let $M$ be a linear bounded automaton. Then, there is a lba $M'$, that accepts the same language and halts on every input.

($\mathsf{DSPACE}(n)$ is all languages accepted by some linear bounded automaton.)

I think, the fact that all languages form $\mathsf{DSPACE}(n)$ are decidable is given by the lemma, isn't it? But how do I prove existence of some decidable language not in $\mathsf{DSPACE}(n)$? I guess I'd need some language that needs bigger and bigger tapes to be recognized so that no lba can do it...is this the right idea?..

Thanks

Comment: E is the decidable languages...

Comment: Depending on your source $\subset$ can mean different things. Commonly it means $\subseteq$, which is *subset or equal*. In this case you are done with your observation that every $\mathsf{DSPACE}(n)$ language is decidable. Finding a decidable language *not* in $\mathsf{DSPACE}(n)$ is only necessary, if $\subset$ is meant as $\subsetneq$, ie. denotes *proper subsets*.

Comment: thank you, yes I should have been more precise, we need to prove proper subset